# Javascript retrieve linebreaks from dom

Tags: javascript, dom, text

I have a text in a paragraph which breaks automatically due to a max p size. Is it possible to somehow extract those line-breaks afterwards from the dom?

For example I have a text like:
`This is an example text that is too long for a line and breaks`
Which breaks after `is` in the dom.

I'd like to generate an array like that: ['This is an example text that is', 'too long for a line and breaks']. And if possible i'd like to also get the dash if a word breaks into syllables.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `split`. `document.getElementById("ptag").textContent.trim().split('\n')`

Comment: @ArunKumar - The line breaks aren't in the text.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if there will be width set to `p` tag then it will add line breaks

Comment: @ArunKumar - No, it won't. Try it. The text will be wrapped in the display, but line breaks will not be present in `textContent`.

Comment: Just tried and it is working with `split('\n')` if we set width to `p` tag

Comment: @ArunKumar - Then you tested it incorrectly. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/tjzrco4q/

Comment: I think i had line breaks in my `p` tag content that's why it was working for me

Comment: @ArunKumar - Yes, if you had line breaks in the HTML, they're faithfully included in `textContent`, but they don't represent where the text is broken when displayed. Any run of whitespace (including line breaks) equals one space in HTML.

Comment: Well, I'd also need wordbreaks. Any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure it's a duplicate. I'm also looking for word breaks which isn't covered in other answer.